# Simple Javascript Physics Engine

Tags: javascript, physics

Is there a simple JavaScript physics engine available that can handle some simple 3D scenarios.

I'm aware of the Box2D implementation but I don't think that can do what I need. In essence I want to simulate the behavior of a ball as it interacts with a hole (like putting in golf). Where, depending on the speed, the ball can spin around the hole etc.

Comment: Is the situation you are looking for not just motion in 3d, but specifically the interaction of objects with variations of solid surfaces, coefficients of restitution, gravity and wind-drag? (or similar)

Comment: impact.js seems quite interesting

Comment: what you describe is not a simple Javascript physics engine, a simple Javascript engine is at https://github.com/orbitingeden

Answer (score 5):

There is a list of javascript physics libraries here: https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Physics-libraries

Answer (score 4):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/do-any-open-source-javascript-3d-physics-engines-exist - this is another post on a similar topic but in stack exchange.

There are also some libraries to be found here:
https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

I don't know if any are 'directly' relevant, but perhaps there's something useful and you can update if you find anything?